# Returning the model in python gurobi interface from a function

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to work on a model in python-gurobi after it is created inside a function and returned by that function.

Example:

```
def createmodel(params):
    m = Model()
    x = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.BINARY)
    m.addConstr(constraint)
    m.setObjective(objectivefunction)
    return m
```

Next, I create the model using initial params

```
model = createmodel(params)
print(model)
```

Notice that I have return the whole model. Print model gives me following which means, model was returned successfully and correctly.

```
<gurobi.Model MIP instance Unnamed: 225 constrs, 230 vars>
```

Next I am trying to change objective of the model. Using `model.setObjective(NewParam * x)`. I get following error. Can anyone help?

`name 'x' is not defined'`

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a local variable only defined within the scope of the function `createmodel()`. Just return both `m` and `x` and you are able to modify the model outside the function:

```
def createmodel(params):
    m = Model()
    x = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.BINARY)
    m.addConstr(constraint)
    m.setObjective(objectivefunction)
    return m, x

model, x = createmodel(params)
```

---

Alternatively, you may query the variables again like this:

```
x = model.getVars()
```

This is unnecessary work, though, since you already had all variables at hand before, so I would go with the first solution.